# Cannot load html file into Webview

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, webview

I cannot load my own `HTML` file into `webView`. I put my index.html file in the assets folder and trying to load it like this:

> myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_assets/myhtml.html")

Then it gives me an error: The file name must end with .xml

Answer (score 0):

Remove the trailing `s` in `android_assets`:

```
myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myhtml.html")
```

Comment: Error is still the same: **Error: The file name must end with .xml** 
Nonsence...

Comment: Where are you getting the error? Is this a compile error? Is it a runtime error? If it is a runtime error, where is the error appearing (in the `WebView`? in Logcat? somewhere else?)?

Comment: Fixed :) Just had to close / open android studio <3